# problem inserting data into database using sql command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have received the following error:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

I don't seem to be able to find the mistake. here is the code:

```
if (Request["su"] == "save")
{
     string sqlCommand = "";
     string fileName = "UsersDB.accdb";
     string tableName = "Table 2";
     string website_name, website_psw;
     website_name = Request["psw_name"];
     website_psw = Request["psw"];

     sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (fname, lname, umail, upassword, gender, age, uid) ";
     sqlCommand += "VALUES ('"+0+ "','" + Session["umail"].ToString() + "','" + website_psw + "','" + website_name +  "')";
     MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName, sqlCommand);
}
```

As for the database, it has 4 rows:

uid, uidd, psw_name, psw

What is the issue in the code which leads to such error?

Comment: Are you certain the table is called 'Table 2'? I'm almost sure you can't have spaces in sql queries when you reference a table like so.

If it is, try adding square brackets like "INSERT INTO [" tableName + "] ..."

Comment: You query for insert having issue as your table having 7 columns and you are passing values for 4 column only

Comment: Post the actual error as well.. this would help from us not guessing what it could be.

Comment: But the most important problem in your query is the SQL Injection free party that you allow to happen on your database

Comment: There's also the obligatory "use an ORM, like Entity Framework or nHibernate rather than try to build SQL statements in your code"

Comment: I will recommend reading a little bit about any ORM: dapper, EntityFramework core, EntityFramework. It will make your request easy.

Comment: And please use the debugger find the containt of your string, look at it, past it into a server management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your INSERT statement is specifying 7 columns (fname, lname, umail, upassword, gender, age, uid) to insert into and only 4 columns of data.

The table name with a space in it is also likely to cause an issue. Enclosing it in square brackets should fix that issue.

You SQL should start like this (if this text: " it has 4 rows: uid, uidd, psw_name, psw" means your table has 4 columns):

INSERT INTO [Table 2] (uid, uidd, psw_name, psw) VALUES (...

Comment: True, but this wouldn't be the source of the "Syntax error" message

Comment: Good point. Potentially the table name with a space in it without surrounding square brackets or similar for the syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this two lines :

```
sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (fname, lname, umail, upassword, gender, 
 age, uid) ";
sqlCommand += "VALUES (\'"+0+ "\',\'" + Session["umail"].ToString() + "\',\'" + 
website_psw + "\',\'" + website_name +  "\')";
```

Comment: First, this answer repeats the error to insert only 4 values when 7 are expected, second there is no need to escape the single quote, neither in C# or MS-Access, third the tablename with spaces is the cause of the syntax error (or some value that contains a single quote)